# What do I do with the files from my ssl certificate download?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am setting up an nginx server for the first time using ssl. I bought an ssl certificate, did the whole thing where I generate a csr. I have activated my ssl purchase and finally downloaded the certificate.

When I downloaded the certificate I got a zip folder. the zip folder had 3 files in it; my_site.ca-bundle , my_site.crt, and my_site.p7b .

I understand how I am supposed to configure nginx , but I don't know the significance of the ca-bundle and the p7b file that was included in the download.

for nginx configuration I just need a crt file and the key from when I generated the CSR:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ...
}
```

Are the ca-bundle and p7b files important, or is the crt file the only thing I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

> Some browsers may complain about a certificate signed by a well-known certificate authority, while other browsers may accept the certificate without issues. This occurs because the issuing authority has signed the server certificate using an intermediate certificate that is not present in the certificate base of well-known trusted certificate authorities which is distributed with a particular browser. In this case the authority provides a bundle of chained certificates which should be concatenated to the signed server certificate. The server certificate must appear before the chained certificates in the combined file:
>
> `$ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt`

Since your SSL vendor has provided you with a CA bundle, you probably need it. Combine your `.crt` and `.ca-bundle` files into a file, put it on the server, and point `ssl_certificate` at it.

You should be the only one with the `ssl_certificate_key` file - you'd likely have generated it when you made your CSR.

Ignore the `.p7b`, I believe it's for IIS.